# Merge multiple jest coverage reports in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: node.js, jestjs, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have been handed the CI/CD pipeline and my second task is to get some coverage reports in the output.  I am very new to Jenkins so any pointers would be helpful!

I have several microservices being built in the Jenkins pipeline.  Each microservice has a set of jest unit tests. The folder structure is as follows, with the Jenkinsfile at the root

```
.Jenkinsfile (at the root)
./service1/code
./service2/code
...
./serviceN/code
```

During the build stage, Jenkins loops through the subfolders and builds the docker images.  After all of the services are built, there is a unit test stage that loops through each service/folder and executes 
`jest --coverage`
Each service outputs a cobertura-coverage.xml file in the folder ./serviceX/coverage/

What I really want is at the end of the unit test stage to combine the individual coverage reports in 
./service1/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
./service2/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml

and publish the combined coverage results with something like this

`step([$class: "CoberturaPublisher", coberturaReportFile: "${jestEnrichers[count]}/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml"])`

Currently I am running the jest coverage like this

```
serviceFolders = ['service1','service2'...] 

for(int count=0; count<serviceFolders.size(); count++){
 echo "Attempting to run JEST tests for ${serviceFolders[count]}"
 sh """
   cd "${WORKSPACE}"/"${serviceFolders[count]}";
   npm install
   npm test
  """
}
```

and I can see the output in the build log for all the services

But I do not know how to combine into one report
if i execute this

```
step([$class: "CoberturaPublisher", coberturaReportFile: "${service1/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml"])
            publishHTML target: [
              allowMissing : false,
              alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
              keepAll              : true,
              reportDir            : "output/coverage/jest",
              reportFiles          : "index.html",
              reportName           : "Test Report"
            ]
```

I see the coverage report in the jenkins UI for the one service so i thought I could wrap this in the same loop that executes
like this

```
serviceFolders = ['service1','service2'...] 

for(int count=0; count<serviceFolders.size(); count++){
 echo "Attempting to run JEST tests for ${serviceFolders[count]}"
 sh """
   cd "${WORKSPACE}"/"${serviceFolders[count]}";
   npm install
   npm test
  """
}
step([$class: "CoberturaPublisher", coberturaReportFile: "${serviceFolders[count]/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml"])
            publishHTML target: [
              allowMissing : false,
              alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
              keepAll              : true,
              reportDir            : "output/coverage/jest",
              reportFiles          : "index.html",
              reportName           : "Test Report"
            ]
```

Jenkins is reporting an error and i see the coverage report just for service1

and this error after the first iteration of the loop (before the second service's jest tests are run

```
[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage results...

[Cobertura] Cobertura coverage report found.

[Pipeline] publishHTML
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /home/jenkins/workspace/licies-pipeline_pipeline-testing/output/coverage/jest to /var/jenkins_home/jobs/xxx-yyy-policies-pipeline/branches/pipeline-testing/builds/208/htmlreports/Test_20Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/home/jenkins/workspace/licies-pipeline_pipeline-testing/output/coverage/jest' does not exist.
[Pipeline] echo
Attempting to run JEST tests for hqaddress
```

Answer (score 0):

I would specify my test sources in a single Jest config, and specify my paths to search in via [regex](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testregex-string-array-string).

Now, in a world of microservices, I would keep these isolated and have my Jenkinsfile per microservice. That way if code is updated in a single sub-directory, you do not kick of a CICD to redeploy your entire product.